# Limiting Kendo UI spinner to integer with no decimals

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

When attempting to use the kendo spinner along with knockout bindings, I am providing the property 'decimals' and setting it to '0'. I wish for no decimals to be displayed nor allow for decimals. The problem is, when I use the spinner I get no decimals, but when the value is selected the displayed number defaults back to a 2 decimal display. I'd like to use this, however I can't unless I'm able to limit display and entry to integer only. Has anyone any experience with this same issue?

```
data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { value: UnpaidMinuteDuration, min: 0,
max: 480, step: 5, decimals: 0 }"
```

[image: Kendo UI Spinner With unwanted Decimals]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not enough the set `decimals` property because it only controls the "input mode".

To also change how your value is displayed so you need to set the [`format` property](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#configuration-format) to a [string format](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting) which does not display decimals:

```
data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { 
     value: UnpaidMinuteDuration, 
     min: 0,
     max: 480, 
     step: 5, 
     decimals: 0,
     format: '0.' }"
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mgb77/).

Comment: nice - good to know. Lets see how easy it is patch this solution onto the Kendo grid filter inputs.